# Ресурсы по masm32 v10 на русском языке

Tags: ассемблер, документация, masm32, masm

Подскажите ресурсы по masm32 v10 - документация, сайты, книги и т.д. - на русском языке.

Answer (score 2):

[wasm.in](https://wasm.in/) - популярный русскоязычный ресурс для любителей низкоуровнего прораммирования. Думаю там найдете все что нужно.

Comment: Я по масму там, практически ни чего не нашел.